# How to insert an NSData object containing multiple strings to an NSMutable object

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, nsdata

I'm receiving an NSData object containing multiple strings and I would like to know how to insert these string in an NSMutableArray separately. I suppose the InsertObject function does not work since it will insert the data as one object in a unique index.

Comment: You need to be more specific about the NSData object. NSData never contains strings, it's just a bunch of bytes. So, if there are "multiple strings" inside that NSData, they have to be stored in some way or another, and you need to extract the characters again.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><account><id>1</id><firstname>XXX</firstname><lastname>XXXX</lastname></account> here is the xml code of the data I receive from the server. In the future there will be images, int, float and  CLLocation2D coordinates - it is encoded in UFT8